# How to customize jwt parsing in Quarkus?

Tags: jwt, quarkus, smallrye, jose4j

I'm using smallrye.jwt as authorization tool. My quarkus app does not generate jwt tokens, but verifies them having secret key.

Problem is that incoming tokens have `sub` claim  of non-string type, but parser expects `java.lang.String` (I receive `45` instead of `"45"`). I don't have access to token generation, so I need it to work with what I have. Apparently there's no way to make it work with microprofile. How can I achieve it?

The error I get (I replaced a few values with `...`):

```
Caused by: org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.InvalidJwtException: JWT (claims->{"iss":"...","iat":...,"exp":...,"nbf":...,"jti":"...","sub":45,"prv":"...","pid": ...}) rejected due to invalid claims or other invalid content. Additional details: [[18] The value of the 'sub' claim is not the expected type (1517 - Cannot cast java.lang.Long to java.lang.String)]
```

My `application.properties`:

```
smallrye.jwt.verify.key-format=JWK
smallrye.jwt.verify.key.location=JWTSecret.jwk
smallrye.jwt.verify.algorithm=HS256
```

Comment: Would something like this be helpful? https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt#custom-factories

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is coming directly from Jose4j, `sub` is a standard JWT claim, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2, and looks like Jose4J is expecting it to be a string as per the RFC7519 text

Comment: You're right, it should be String according to the standard. I'm looking for a way of customizing verifying behavior, since I can't change already given jwt.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to provide custom factory implementation of JWTCallerPrincipalFactory, where I manually parsed json and replaced "sub" claim with the same claim of String type.

```kotlin
import javax.annotation.Priority
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative
import io.smallrye.jwt.auth.principal.*
import org.jose4j.jwt.JwtClaims
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.InvalidJwtException
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.util.*
import com.your.company.SignatureValidator // this is your custom validator for your algorithm

@ApplicationScoped
@Alternative
@Priority(1)
class MyJWTCallerPrincipalFactory : JWTCallerPrincipalFactory() {
    @Inject
    @field:Default
    lateinit var signatureValidator: SignatureValidator

    override fun parse(token: String, authContextInfo: JWTAuthContextInfo): JWTCallerPrincipal {
        return try {
            val isSignatureValid = signatureValidator.validate(token)
            if (!isSignatureValid) {
                throw ForbiddenException("Invalid Token Signature")
            }

            val json = String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(token.split("\\.".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }
                .toTypedArray()[1]), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            val jwtClaims = JwtClaims.parse(json)
            val subClaimValue = jwtClaims.getClaimValue("sub")
            jwtClaims.setClaim("sub", subClaimValue.toString())
            DefaultJWTCallerPrincipal(jwtClaims)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            throw ParseException(ex.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code misses the signature verification step, so you need to add a jose4j verification code as well. If you'd like, I can update the default `JWTCallerPrincipalFactory` implementation so that you can extend it and delegate to its signature verification code, open a `smallrye-jwt` issue please if it can be of interest

Comment: Opened https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-jwt/issues/650, will look at a bit later

Comment: Though thinking more about it, the signature verification is implicit there and it may have to be decrypted first, which would be hard to move into a self-contained single utility function so I think best is to use Jose4j verification directly in your factory, https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWS%20Examples#markdown-header-signature-verification-using-jws, sorry about the confusion

Comment: You're right, I will edit the answer with signature verification included once I implement it. Thank you

Comment: I've added a few lines indicating signature validation. However I noticed one thing: the errors thrown inside `catch` block won't be intercepted by Quarkus'es ExceptionMapper

Comment: A lot of work has gone recently into fixing various issues related to intercepting security exceptions. In the proactive auth case which is a default, the security chain runs before JAX-RS, so for now using Vertx fault filters is required to intercept, if the proactive auth is disabled then the exception mappers will work - try the latest versions